# How do I report an issue with datagrip to jetbrains?

Tags: postgresql, datagrip

I am having an issue with datagrip when creating foreign keys for postgres 9.6 .

Is there an issue tracker so I can let the devs at jetbrains know about my issue?

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE

Answer (score 0):

Many ways!

1. The easiest: you can just ask here. I am the PMM of DataGrip and I monitor all the questions with `datagrip` tag.
2. The official way, and the best for us, our issue tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/DBE
3. We also read and answer in twitter: https://twitter.com/datagrip
4. For those who are lazy and in 2000 still, the email also works: datagrip[at]jetbrains.com